# Regex: Extract text between 2 group of characters where the last group is optional

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling to create a regex capable of extract data between 2 group of characters where the last group of characters  don't appear in all the matches.

I would like to obtain the following data

```
https://www.myurl.com/tag/important-info-1/page/34/
https://www.myurl.com/tag/otherimportant-info-3
https://www.myurl.com/tag/moreimportantinfo/page/1
https://www.myurl.com/tag/otherimportant-info-4/
```

and the result

```
important-info-1
otherimportant-info-3
moreimportantinfo
otherimportant-info-4
```

Comment: it 'tag' always the same, or does that change?

Comment: it's always the same :)

Comment: `your_string.split('/')[4]` ??

Comment: @001 I'm with you here - with this level of consistency, RegEx is overkill. `str.split('/')` is your friend :)

Comment: yes I thought in that option, but  I have on the same input data other links with different structure. so is not possible to split the string. that's why I wanna use regex for this case

Comment: how about regex similar to `.*/tag/([^/]+)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ?-operator is your friend here, as it signals that an expression is optional:

The regex

```
https://www\.myurl\.com/tag/([^/]+)(second_group)?
```

matches strings containing the second group as well as those without it.